# How to remove default zones (or change layout) from blog default homepage?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, css, blog

Yes, i can use css

```
.ms-blog-MainArea {max-width:100%;}
.ms-blog-LeftColumn {display:none;}
.ms-blog-postList {max-width:100%;margin-right:0px;}
```

but that is looks like "Piece of *kludge*".

PS Is there any way to use posts view on my custom pages? 
It is an alternative solution.
[image: view]

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a copy of the default page layout and edit in designer. You can then create pages from that layout.

Answer (score 0):

The Blog web parts/apps can be added to custom pages too, whether they are wiki pages or web part pages doesn't matter.

Alternatively the layout can be at least partly changed on each page (with a '`Blog`'-layout) part of `Posts` list. You could e.g. replace the default LHS web part area with your default navigation by replacing the whole `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server"></asp:Content>` of pages with '`Blog`'-layout.

These pages can be seen on Designer at `All Files` > `Lists` > `Posts`.